# List of figures problem

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I need to make a list of figures where there is reference to some pictures I've included in my document. I've been using

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{subsection}{\arabic{slike}.\hspace{5mm}\hyperref[sl:1]{Picture 1.}}
```

but it's just not working. I must say that my pictures are not included inside a `figure` environment, I've included them inside a minipage.

What should I do ?

Comment: Does this help: `\addtocontents{lof}{\arabic{slike}.\hspace{5mm}\hyperref[sl:1]{Picture 1.}}`

Comment: hmm.. no :S
I need to do this for homework, I need to duplicate this file: 
https://sites.google.com/a/ictlab.com.ba/tptp2012/zadace/zadaca4/zadaca4.pdf
2nd and 3rd page, and I'm stuck on the "Popis slika" ,that'd be list of figures in english..
I can't create list of figures :S

Comment: Can you please show us in a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us which document class you use and how you include one figure in your document ...

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/Vim_LW2i/V_18_IC_12.html
here is a tex file that I've been working on.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a `figure` environment to get a figure caption, that is placed in the List of figures. The `caption` package provides the command `\captionof{<float type>}{<caption text>}` that lets you place captions outside figure environments, for example

```
\captionof{figure}{A caption}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\vspace{1cm} % just for this example
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{A figure caption, not in the \texttt{figure}-environment.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "tables of floats" lists list floats. Either you use the figure environment or define your own floats, e.g. by using the float package. Exactly how to set up the tables depends on the document class.

Comment: but I can't use figure environment because I got this for my homework and I need to do it with minipage :S